# how to run and compile Android Apps on AVD Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

please help me... :( 
I downloaded Android ADT from google play and update all of it's SDK and etc to last version and also I've installed Java Runtime(SE) last version.
Now according to any basic learning courses, I want to run the first App "Hello World!" in AVD.
For example :  from menu I just click **"new"** and select **"Android Application Project".** then I just set App Name, project Name and Package Name just as like all trainings and there is no error in here and everythings goes well. 
after that I must choose my SDKs and in order to lessons, I was choose combo boxes as bellow :
[image: New Android Application Window]

Then I didn't change and left all options to their default. and finally click on Finish button.
now I can see my first program environment but in design mode.
**the problems are here :**
 at last, I want run my first program with AVD as shown in bellow :
[image: Edit AVD]

and run AVD. 
1st problem : after long time(almost 3 or 6 min) AVD simulate Andriod smart phone. 
2nd problem : in menu screen i can't see my first App Icon so I can't Run It.
3rd problem : If I want Run AVD with Intelx86, the emulator Run after horrible long time and say this error:

> Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_AVD_for_test_5_1in_WVGA'
>   emulator: Failed to open the HAX device!
>   HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
>   emulator: Open HAX device failed

---

**The Ways I tried to solve my problems** :
1st problem: In Edit AVD I check **snapshot** and uncheck **host GPU**
**Result**: the first Running takes long same ago but after first time comes fast.
2nd problem: I'm really don't have any Idea for this :( 
**Result**: I'm Disappointed in Android Development Programs. It's very complicated and time-consuming .
3rd problem: I even check **Intel Vitalization** on my System Bios and i'm sure it's work because i already run Windows 2008 R2 on VMware machine that need to this Option.
**Result**: I Still have that problem... AVD does not work in Intel x86 Mode.
In Finally, my system configuration is :
OS: Window 7 Ultimate with last Updates.
CPU: Intel Corei7 2630QM 2.00GHz.
RAM:8 GB.
Graphic: Intel and 2GB Nvidia.

**so please help me. I'm really like to learn Android Programming :((**

---

now thanks to **Rohan Kandwal** I can run emulator very fast in Intel X86 Mode but still i can't see my app Icon
[image]

Comment: are you running the application? The app won't already be present on the emulator if you haven't **run** the app.

Comment: your first comment : I don't get your question . but i first config ADV and Run it. so what was you mean?

Comment: you run the emulator but not the app. You have to run the app to make it install on the emulator

Comment: Ok got you ... but how please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the application not present in the menu, I think that you are not running the project from eclipse and just looking into the emulator. Please run the project from the IDE that you are using eg. Eclipse.

If have **run** the app and still not seeing it on the emulator then please post the **logcat**.

For the problem regarding the HAX, go to the folder

```
[Android SDK Root]\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
```

then run `IntelHaxm.exe` and install. [image: HAX]

For running the app, `right click on the project > Run as > Android Application`[image: run app]

Comment: thanks now I can run in Intel x86 mode ant it's loading and running is super fast but still in menu i can't see my app Icon. I'll take a pics now.

Comment: Did you run the app from eclipse?

Comment: I think Yes, because I run eclips.exe but the IDE title is Andriod Developer Tools that is very similar to eclips

Comment: After running the app you will see your app on the emulator. If this solved your problem then please mark this question as solved and upvote it.

Comment: @RohanKandwal: I have the SDK installed, but I don't see that folder. Is there any other place where I can get that HAXM installer?